# Adding data to database (intermediate model)

Tags: django, django-orm

How can I add a car(`Car`) to garage (`Garage`) if I have an intermediate model? I can not understand this.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField()    

class GarageCar(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Garage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Garage_Name", max_length=30)
    cars = models.ManyToManyField('GarageCar', blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner_garage', verbose_name='Owner Garage')
```

views

```
def add_car(request, car_id):
```

---

If I have two models (Car and Garage with field cars = models.ManyToManyField('Car') I create something like this:

```
def add_car(request, car_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        car = Car.objects.get(id = car_id)
        e = car.garage_set.create(name='example_name', owner=user)

    return render_to_response('add.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make a couple of changes to your models:

1. The intermediate model `GarageCar` needs to have a foreign key to `Car` and `Garage`.
2. When you define the many to many field, use the `through` argument to specify the intermediate table.

Change your models as follows:

```
 class GarageCar(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car')
    garage = models.ForeignKey('garage')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Garage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Garage_Name", max_length=30)
    cars = models.ManyToManyField('Car', through='GarageCar')
```

Then, you can add a car to a garage with the following:

```
GarageCar.objects.create(car=car,
                         garage=garage,
                         quantity=1,
                         )
```

See the docs on [extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for more information.